# Django migration: how to only allow running in --fake mode?

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations, django-1.8

I am upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.8

As a result there are quite a lot of migrations and some backwards (in)compatibility issues which I am solving with migrations that 'patch' the database with missing tables.

Some of the migrations should only run in `--fake` mode so I'd like to know if there's a way, **within the `000x_migration.py` file**, to do that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SeparateDatabaseAndState`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate) operation to effectively always fake those specific operations. If you put the original operations in the `state_operations`, Django will think they are applied, but they will never have any effect on the database.